# MethodChannelFilePicker Platform exception: PlatformException(read_external_storage_denied, User did not allow reading external storage, null, null)

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, android-permissions

I am Trying to pick images from my device but it is unable to get the access of file storage and it is always saying you don't have enough permission. Using sdk 33

i have permission this

```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="33" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="33" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO"/>
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml File

Answer (score 0):

some time is need to run

```
flutter clean
```

and run application again